# Generate array from comparison

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I want TPP to be an array with the TPP value for each threshold.
The print should be like: TPP is: n1, n2...

```
threshold=[0, 6, 15]
df=[3,13,19,21]
y_true=[0,0,1,0]
y_pred=np.where(df<threshold,1,0)
cm=confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred)
TP=cm[0,0]
FN=cm[0,1]
TPP=TP/(TP+FN)
print('TPP is:',TPP)
```

Comment: Why the `s` tag if you're using Python?

Comment: "threshold" should probably be a constant, if you're detecting on the values of "df"  (which in python is an overloaded name)

Comment: by TPP do you mean "true positive rate"?  If so it should be a single number in the range [0.0, 1.0]

Comment: I dont have the slightest idea as to why there is a 's' tag. Probably a lack of attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this code achieves your goal:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np

threshold = [0, 6, 15, 20]
df        = [3,13,19,21]
y_true    = [0,0,1,0]

print('TPP is:', end=' ')
for idx, i in enumerate(threshold):
    y_pred = np.where(np.array(df) < i,1,0)
    are_ones = y_true == np.ones(len(y_true))
    predicted_as_zero = y_pred == np.zeros(len(y_true))
    TP = sum( are_ones   & np.array(y_pred) )
    FN = sum( are_ones & predicted_as_zero )
    if idx+1 == len(threshold):
        print(TP/(TP+FN), end='')
    else:
        print(TP/(TP+FN), end=', ')
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to store TP and FN as arrays, instead of just printing one at a time?